# TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 25: 'end', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am trying to load the `main_template.html` in `hello.html` code.
but some error is showing to register or load the tag. How do I fix this?

**myapp.views.py**

```
def hello(request):
# return HttpResponse("welcome to my app")
today = datetime.datetime.now().date
daysOfWeek = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
return render(request,"hello.html",{"today":today,"days_of_week" : daysOfWeek})
```

**myproject.templates.hello.html**

```
{% extends "main_template.html" %}

{% block title %}My Hello Page{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

hello world!!! <p>today is {{today}}</p>
we are

{% if today.day is 1 %}
the first day of the month

{%elif today.day is 30 %}
the last day of the month

{%else %}
i dont know

{%endif%}
<p>
     {% for day in days_of_week %}
     {{day}}
  </p>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**myproject.templates.main_template.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    {% block title %}Page Title{%end block%}
</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
Body Content
{% end block%}
</body>
</html>
```

**error occured:**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/myapp/hello/
Django Version: 1.11.20
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 4: 'end', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Exception Location: /home/divum/PycharmProjects/untitled3/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in parse, line 515
Python Executable:  /home/divum/PycharmProjects/untitled3/venv/bin/python2.7
```

**Python Version:   2.7.14**

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 4: 'end', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Comment: Did you try writing "endblock" exactly as it appears in the error message?

Comment: MONINGI KAVYA - @blhsing answer is correct. Why don't you accept it?

Comment: @Headmaster This question is (to me) [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (typo). Answers (in my opinion) shouldn't be rewarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no space between `end` and `block` in the keyword `endblock`.

Change:

```
{%end block%}
```

to:

```
{% endblock %}
```